# How can i use 2 functions in a columnDef render

Tags: datatables

i am using Datatables and have a table with a date column, im trying to use the columnDefs render: to firstly change the format of the date, and then secondly change the text colour conditionally,

```
//date formatting - this works on its own
columnDefs: [{
targets: 6,
render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment( 'Do MMM YYYY' )
}]
```

```
//colour changing - this also works on its own
columnDefs: [{
targets: 6,
render: function ( data, type, row ) {
   var color = '#6a7a8c';
   if (data <  todayDate) {
      color = 'red';
   } 
   if (data <=  sevenDays) {
      color = 'orange';
   }
   return '<span style="color:' + color + '">' + data + '</span>';
 }
}]
```

I am struggling to combine these 2 together, they dont seem to work at the same time, only one of them works, only the colour change works when i try to use both of these.

i have tried

```
// here only the colour changes, format doesnt
columnDefs: [
        {
      targets: 6,

       render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment( 'Do MMM YYYY' )
    } ,
        ],
        columnDefs: [
        {
      targets: 6,

      render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                        console.log(data);
                      var color = '#6a7a8c';
                      if (data <  todayDate) {
                        color = 'red';
                      } 
                      if (data <=  sevenDays) {
                        color = 'orange';
                      }

                      return '<span style="color:' + color + '">' + data + '</span>';
                    }
    } ,
        ],
```

any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please combine your date formating and color changing logic into one Function in below manner:

```
columnDefs: [{
targets: 6,
render: function ( data, type, row ) {
   var color = '#6a7a8c';
   if (data <  todayDate) {
      color = 'red';
   } 
   if (data <=  sevenDays) {
      color = 'orange';
   }
   return '<span style="color:' + color + '">' + moment(data).format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm")+ '</span>';
 }
}]
```